# Extract and load hierarchy of records in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, etl

I'm trying to extract and load a complete hierarchy of records based off of a single record in the root table. The table graph is multiple levels deep and I'd like to not write the entire set of queries by hand.

The table structure is something like this:

```
ParentTable
-ParentId
-Name

ChildTable
-ParentId
-ChildId
-Name

GrandchildTable
-ChildId
-GrandchildId
-Name
```

Keeping in mind that my actual table count is closer to 100, how could I extract and load all the data relevant to a parent based on ParentId?

Comment: This should help: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm but can you please post an example of your problem so that we can provide a better solution than just a link?